# I can't find the file /usr/src/linux in Kali Linux

Tags: linux

I need to edit the source file /usr/src/linux/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c as it is mentioned in some tutorial, but I can't find it. I'm new to Kali what should I do ?

Comment: Did you re-compile the Kernel to add the required dependencies?   https://www.kali.org/docs/development/recompiling-the-kali-linux-kernel/

Comment: You need to install the kernel source.

Comment: I should add that in a base Kali machine (mine here), usr/src is there but is empty.

Comment: I tried "sudo apt install -y linux-source-4.9" but the is an error message: E: Unable to locate package linux-source-4.9
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-source-4.9'

Comment: Kali is at Kernel 5.9 or 5.10 depending on upgrades you did, so modify the Kali article for your Kernel version ( uname -rs)

Comment: I issued the command : apt install -y linux-source-$(uname -rs) . and I got the following errors:E: Unable to locate package linux-source-Linux
E: Unable to locate package 5.7.0-kali1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '5.7.0-kali1-amd64'